# Leaflet Draw spritesheet icon issue - Missing and then not aligned

Tags: css, icons, leaflet, toolbar, draw

I have incorporated leaflet draw in one of my projects. My issue is that the icons were not displaying in the tool bar. It looked like this:

[image]

Looking around I found [THIS](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/issues/617) post and did as it stated. I located the spritesheet in the Leaflet Draw folder and linked to it like htis:

```
    .leaflet-draw-toolbar a {
            background-image: url('E:/MappingProject/Leaflet.Draw/src/images/spritesheet.png');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
```

I ended up with this:

[image]

I can't seem to find any other solutions to get this spritesheet to line up in the boxes. It looks like instead of pulling individual icons, it's putting the entire sheet in each button.

Here is my code to instantiate the L.FeatureGroup() and L.Control.Draw():

```
    function logIn(){
        map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
        OpenStreetMap_HOT.addTo(map);
        $("#logInScreen").css('display', 'none');
        addSideBars();
        addDrawToMap();
    }        

/////////////////////////////////////////////
        //DRAW FUNCTIONALITY
///////////////////////////////////////////
        function addDrawToMap(){
            map.addControl(drawControl);
            map.addLayer(drawnItems);
        }
        var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
            var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
                position: 'topright',
                draw: {
                    polyline: true,
                    polygon: true,
                    circle: true,
                    marker: true
                },
                edit: {
                    featureGroup: drawnItems,
                    remove: true
                }
            });
```

Any one have experience with this?

Comment: What build system are you using?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance. What is a "build system"? I'm using Brackets and I am linking to the leaflet libraries using these links:                              <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.js"></script>

Comment: A build system is a system of tools like Gulp or Rollup that handles compilation of your project.

 Could you post the code that you use in instantiating the leaflet draw object(s)?

Comment: Sure. Just updated the post with the code. I can draw objects, but they do not stay on the map. They immediately disappear when I mouseup.

Comment: @MarcusHolden As for saving features you draw, you have to manually listen to Leaflet draw events and add the layers to the map. See http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html#l-draw-event Please feel free to open a new question should you need help for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most probably you miss the [Leaflet-draw CSS file](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/blob/v1.0.2/src/leaflet.draw.css).

It is in that file that the CSS rules like `.leaflet-draw-toolbar a` are defined.

**Example without this file, but with your CSS rule:**

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([48.86, 2.35], 11);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
  position: 'topright'
});
map.addControl(drawControl);
```

```css
.leaflet-draw-toolbar a {
  background-image: url('https://unpkg.com/leaflet-draw@1.0.2/dist/images/spritesheet.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-IkGU/uDhB9u9F8k+2OsA6XXoowIhOuQL1NTgNZHY1nkURnqEGlDZq3GsfmdJdKFe1k1zOc6YU2K7qY+hF9AodA==" crossorigin=""></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-draw@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.draw-src.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 200px"></div>
```

**Example with this file:**

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([48.86, 2.35], 11);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
  position: 'topright'
});
map.addControl(drawControl);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-IkGU/uDhB9u9F8k+2OsA6XXoowIhOuQL1NTgNZHY1nkURnqEGlDZq3GsfmdJdKFe1k1zOc6YU2K7qY+hF9AodA==" crossorigin=""></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-draw@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.draw-src.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-draw@1.0.2/dist/leaflet.draw-src.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 200px"></div>
```

Comment: That did it. despite the fact that I was pointing to the css/js files locally, it still didn't work. linking to them through unpkg.com did, however. Whacky! I appreciate the extra set of eyes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Angular**, just add a link to the css file in your `styles.css`

```
@import "~leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
@import "~leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw.css";
```