# Leaflet Draw icons do not appear in production mode on Vue

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

I have a Vue application using Leaflet as a map library. On the map, I've added a toolbar using Leaflet Draw and a button with Leaflet EasyButton. I give an image in order to illustrate below:

**Development**

[image]

The problem has started to appear when I created a build version of my Vue application to save on my server. The Leaflet Draw icons do not appear anymore. Just the Leaflet EasyButton icon is showing.

**Production**

[image]

My code is as follows:

```js
  this.llmap = L.map('map-id', {...})

  let vectorLayerDraw = L.featureGroup([])

  this.llmap.addControl(new L.Control.Draw({
    position: 'topright',
    draw: {
      ...
      rectangle: {
        shapeOptions: {
          color: '#000000',
          opacity: 0.2,
          fillOpacity: 0.1
        }
      }
    },
    edit: {
      featureGroup: vectorLayerDraw,
      poly: {
        allowIntersection: false
      }
    }
  }))
```

Would anyone know what can be happening?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: High chance this is more likely a webpack configuration issue.

Comment: Yes, it is, however I was able to fix the problem by overwriting Leaflet Draw CSS. Thank you.

Comment: Good job having found a solution by yourself! Please consider moving it as an _answer_ below and to accept it, so that people know your issue is fixed.

Comment: Sure. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the question on the internet and I've found the following solution:

```css
.leaflet-draw-toolbar a {
  background-image: url('../assets/spritesheet.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: transparent !important;
}
```

Where I add the image manually on my static folder and I overwrite the background-image.

Sources: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48658863/8447990) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53576732/8447990)

Thank you so much.